# ListBox insert from a dictionary and i need to get the value and the key seperate

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox, key

i am trying to make favourites in my application and i need to show a form that have the names of the favourite in a ListBox.
When select a name and click the choose button i want to put the name and the Url in different textboxes and this is my code any ideas.

```
       private void EditFourites_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();//put the selected value from the listbox to the textbox1 and this is my problem i want to make textbox1.text takes only the key of the listbox1.text


    }

    private void ListBox() 
    {
        FavoriteXml FV = new FavoriteXml();//the favouritXml class is a class where i get the information about favourites
        Dictionary<string, string> Favourite = FV.GetFavouriteCombo();//GetFavouriteCombo() will get the value as dictionary

        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(Favourite, null);

        listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
    }

     private void EditSpecificFavourite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FavoriteXml FV = new FavoriteXml();
        FV.EditFavourite(textBox1.Text.ToString(),textBox2.Text.ToString());//this is the EditFavourite where i want to change the specific favourite
        ListBox();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the datavalue of the selected listboxitem into your second textbox you use this code:

```
textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Okay this work and get me the selected value but i want to put the key too in another textbox

Comment: what do you mean by key? A listboxitem can only hold 2 values, the one that you can see and the "SelectedValue".

Comment: I mean when I when I do binding source for the listbox I am insertinging two values from the dictionary the key and the value in your answer I get only the values I want the key too of the dictionary